# $http get returns html instead of JSON Object Spring Security with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring, authentication, spring-security

I can't find the response of the login

Okay here's my mapping

locahost:8080/ is my index.html but if not logged in
page will be redirected to /login

but the thing is I can't get pass through my function because the return of response.data is the html itself

I just followed a tutorial and merged it with my webapp but can't seem to do it right

after I login
[image]

you see I need to get the response.data to get info for authentication

```
$scope.login = function () {

        var base64Credential = btoa($scope.username + ':' + $scope.password);

        // calling GET request for getting the user details
        console.log($scope.username);
        console.log($scope.password);
        console.log(base64Credential);

        $http.get('user', {headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64Credential}}).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.password = null;
            console.log(response);
            if (response.data.authenticated) {

                $scope.message = '';
                // setting the same header value for all request calling from this app
                $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + base64Credential;
                $scope.user = response.data.principal;
                //$sessionStorage.authenticate = $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
                //$sessionStorage.showLogin = $scope.showLogin = true;
                //$sessionStorage.user = $scope.user;
                $scope.isLogin = true;
                console.log(response.data.principal.role);
                //if (response.data.principal.role != "ADMIN") {
                //    $scope.notAdmin = true;
                //}

                var host = $window.location.host;
                var landingUrl = "http://" + host + "/";
                $window.location.href = landingUrl;
            } else {

                $scope.message = 'Authetication Failed !';
            }
        }, function errorCallback(response) {

            return response;
            //error
        });
    }
```

This is my MainController.java
[image]

My webconfig

```
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth
            // using in memory authentication
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                    // adding Administrator user
            .withUser("admin").password("admin").authorities("ADMIN")
            // using add() method for adding new user
            .and()
                    // adding a user without Administrator authority
            .withUser("user").password("user").authorities("USER");
}



@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    super.configure(web);
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            // starts authorizing configurations
    .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/font/**", "/libs/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");

    }
```

First console is my current project
Second console is my old project with the same codes
[image]

/user returns html wth :(
[image]